# Why does my bootloader code works everywhere except my laptop if I have a BIOS Parameter Block?

Tags: assembly, nasm, bootloader, bios

I write an ext2 bootloader. Some BIOSes boot USB sticks in floppy emulation mode and then overwrites the parts where the BPB should be. This is why I have a fake BPB. But if I use a BPB, even though BOCHS, QEMU and even my PC boot it, my laptop doesn't. Without BPB it boots my code.
What have I done wrong or is the BIOS on my laptop crap? Do I really need a BPB to be safe?

My code:

```
org 0x7c00
bits 16

    jmp     _start
    db      0x90

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; BIOS Parameter Block (BIOS sometimes overwrites the code otherwise)
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bsOEMName:                      db              "mkfs.fat"
bpbBytesPerSector:              dw              512
bpbSectorsPerCluster:           db              1
bpbReservedSectorCount:         dw              1
bpbFATCount:                    db              2
bpbRootEntryCount:              dw              224
bpbTotalSector16:               dw              2880
bpbMedia:                       db              0xf0
bpbFatSize16:                   dw              9
bpbSectorsPerTrack:             dw              18
bpbHeadCount:                   dw              2
bpbHiddenSectors:               dd              0
bpbTotalSector32:               dd              0
bsDriveNum:                     db              0
bsReserved1:                    db              0
bsBootSignature:                db              0x29
bsVolumeID:                     dd              0x2d7e5a1a
bsVolumeLabel:                  db              "NO NAME    "
bsFileSysType:                  db              "FAT12   "
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%include "bootutil.inc"

_start:
; Initialize segment registers
    xor     ax, ax
    mov     ds, ax
    mov     es, ax
    mov     gs, ax
    mov     fs, ax

; Initialize stack
    mov     ss, ax
    mov     sp, 0x7c00

; Save drive number
    mov     [bsDriveNum], dl

; Reset disk
    mov     cx, 3
.reset:
    dec     cx
    mov     ah, 0
    mov     dl, [bsDriveNum]
    int     0x13
    jecxz   print_error
    jc      .reset

; Getting disk geometry
    mov     ah, 0x8
    mov     dl, [bsDriveNum]
    int     0x13

; Save disk geometry
    inc     dh
    mov     [bpbHeadCount], dh
    and     cl, 0x3f
    mov     [bpbSectorsPerTrack], cl

    mov     ax, 2
    call    lba2chs

; Read superblock
    mov     byte [try], 3
.rsb:
    dec     byte [try]
    mov     dl, [bsDriveNum]
    mov     al, 2
    mov     ah, 0x2
    mov     bx, 0x7e00
    int     0x13
    cmp     byte [try], 0
    je      print_error
    jc      .rsb

; Get block size
    mov     eax, 1024
    mov     cl, byte [0x7e00 + 24]
    shl     eax, cl
    mov     [BLOCK_SIZE], eax

    mov     si, failed_info ; Just for testing
    call    print

    jmp     $

print_error:
    mov     si, failed_info
    call    print

    jmp     $

failed_info:                    db          "No operating system found", 0xa, 0xd, 0x0
try:                            db          0

; ext2 infos
BLOCK_SIZE:                     dd          0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

bootutil.inc:

```
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Prints a string onto the screen
; Parameters:
; SI = Zero-terminated string
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
print:
    pusha

.start:
    lodsb
    or      al, al
    jz      .end
    mov     ah, 0xe
    int     0x10
    jmp     .start

.end:
    popa
    ret
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Converts LBA to CHS
; Parameters:
; AX = LBA
; Returns:
; CL = Sector
; DH = Head
; CH = Cylinder
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
lba2chs:
    div     byte [bpbSectorsPerTrack]
    mov     cl, ah
    inc     cl

    xor     ah, ah
    div     byte [bpbHeadCount]
    mov     dh, ah
    mov     ch, al

    ret
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Minimized code:

```
org 0x7c00
bits 16

    jmp _start
    db 0x90

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; BIOS Parameter Block (BIOS sometimes overwrites the code otherwise)
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bsOEMName:                      db              "mkfs.fat"
bpbBytesPerSector:              dw              512
bpbSectorsPerCluster:           db              1
bpbReservedSectorCount:         dw              1
bpbFATCount:                    db              2
bpbRootEntryCount:              dw              224
bpbTotalSector16:               dw              2880
bpbMedia:                       db              0xf0
bpbFatSize16:                   dw              9
bpbSectorsPerTrack:             dw              18
bpbHeadCount:                   dw              2
bpbHiddenSectors:               dd              0
bpbTotalSector32:               dd              0
bsDriveNum:                     db              0
bsReserved1:                    db              0
bsBootSignature:                db              0x29
bsVolumeID:                     dd              0x2d7e5a1a
bsVolumeLabel:                  db              "NO NAME    "
bsFileSysType:                  db              "FAT12   "
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

_start:
    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0x7c00

    mov si, msg
    call print

    jmp $

print:
    pusha

.start:
    lodsb
    or      al, al
    jz      .end
    mov     ah, 0xe
    int     0x10
    jmp     .start

.end:
    popa
    ret

msg: db "hello", 0xa, 0xd, 0x0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

That didn't work too

Comment: On your laptop when you have a BPB present and it doesn't boot - do you mean it doesn't even recognize the disk as bootable and doesn't run any code in the bootloader or does it run the bootloader but it doesn't work correctly?

Comment: Is your laptop set to boot as USB Floppy emulation or is it set to USB Hard Drive emulation?

Comment: On my laptops BIOS setup there is no option to turn USB Floppy emulation on or off. I can only turn on Legacy Support and USB Boot. Only a cursor blinks at top left instead of printing the text. But if I remove the BPB it prints the text. It's also weird because when I replace the BPB with "times 58 db 0" it works. What if I used FAT? Then I need the BPB

Comment: I have done this already. It didn't print the text with a BPB. Maybe it's important to know that my bootloader is in a VBR. The MBR was created by gparted

Comment: But even though, my PC, BOCHS and QEMU can run it. As well my laptop without a BPB

Comment: I'm asking this all before I get to the fact that there is a problem in your `lba2chs` code. Because there are potentially 2 problems. One is that it isn't running ANY code in your boot record or it has started running the boot record code but it has failed to read the right sector containing the superblock.

Comment: I will edit my question and show the minimized code

Comment: I checked the memory dump in BOCHS and compared it with wxHexEditor of my USB drive. According to that, the right sector is at 0x7e00

Comment: I added the minimized version of my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216708/discussion-between-michael-petch-and-xorda).